# Responsive blog post display in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working on porting some features of a website to a native Android app, I am new to Android development so I'm still working out some of the kinks. I want to display a responsive blog post (Twitter Bootstrap) in an Activity, assuming that this will allow the post to fit the screen it is being viewed on and allow me to maintain the post's content.

As an Android novice, the first thing that comes to mind is using a WebView widget to load a minimal version of the post into the Activity. I also saw that it is possible to display HTML in a TextView but obviously not something that includes Twitter Bootstrap - and I'm assuming it would not be responsive.

Would a WebView be the right thing to use here? What are some alternatives, pros, cons?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is little broad to answer. but yes, a webview will be  useful if you wish not to create whole blogpost's UI in native android, while you can show it in webview, which will preserve its all characteristics that it had when opened in a browser.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. Is there any sort of common practice for this? The post generally just contains photos and text. What I have at the moment is a minimalist Bootstrap page being loaded into a Web view. Trying to learn best practices.

Comment: Also, I am building an API that is consumed by Retrofit in the app, so obtaining data is no problem. Just looking for the best way to display a post that contains HTML

Comment: html one shows in textview is fairly simple as compared to what we get in a webpage. So webview is the answer so far as I know.